# assigning integer variable to image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

so i have a few images from 0.png to 9.png they will be used for the score. 
now i want the images to be displayed based on the current score. I could do something like this:

```
scoreImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", score]];
```

the above code means that i have to create an infinite number of images to cover the score.
is there a more efficient way to do this? using only 10 images for each digit e.g 0.png 1.png 2.png... 9.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you do 
scoreImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", score % 100]];?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MOST` efficient way to do this is to use a view object that displays text directly, like a UILabel. Then you can simply set it's font, size, and style to the desired values and set its text to the value you want.

You could craft a custom font that contains just numeric digits, and use that. I've never created a custom font, but I know it's possible.

Failing that, you could create a custom ScoreView class that contains 4 UIImageView objects. It would have an integer property score, and when you set the score value, it would install the correct digit images into it's different component image views.

The code to calculate the digit values might look like this:

```
int score = 7596;
int remainder = score;

int thousandsValue = remainder / 1000;
remainder -= thousandsValue*1000;

int hundredsValue = remainder /100;
remainder -= hundredsValue*100;

int tensValue = remainder/10;
int onesValue = remainder % 10;

NSLog(
      @"For %d, thousandsValue = %d, hundredsValue = %d, tensValue = %d,  onesValue = %d",
      score,
      thousandsValue,
      hundredsValue,
      tensValue,
      onesValue
      );
```

Then use those values to build image filenames for your thousands digit, hundreds digit, tens digit, and ones digits image views.

Finally, load and install the images into each imageView.